# JavaScript object EventSource

Tags: javascript, object

I tried to get the BidPrice object. I am getting this data in an EventSource and would like to process it.

```
    var data = {
      "status" : "OK",
      "Quote" : {
        "EUR/USD" : {
          "eventSymbol" : "EUR/USD",
          "bidTime" : 1444932337000,
          "bidExchangeCode" : "",
          "bidPrice" : 1.29805,
          "bidSize" : 1,
          "askTime" : 1444932337000,
          "askExchangeCode" : "",
          "askPrice" : 1.29807,
          "askSize" : 1
        },
        "USD/AUD" : {
          "eventSymbol" : "USD/AUD",
          "bidTime" : 1444932337000,
          "bidExchangeCode" : "",
          "bidPrice" : 0.97457,
          "bidSize" : 1,
          "askTime" : 1444932337000,
          "askExchangeCode" : "",
          "askPrice" : 0.97464,
          "askSize" : 1
        }
      }
    };

    for(var key in data){
        console.log(data[key].Quote.bidPrice);
        //my goal is to output this: console.log('EUR/USD bid price is 1.29805');
    }
```

Comment: `data.Quote["EUR/USD"].bidPrice` <- should be straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is close. You need to iterate through the [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on `data.Quote` instead. See the working example below, which uses the [`forEach` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through the quote object's keys.

The basic idea is to do this:

```
Object.keys(data["Quote"]).forEach(function (k) {
    console.log(k + " bid price is: " + data["Quote"][k]["bidPrice"]);
});
```

And the full example:

```js
var data = {
  "status" : "OK",
  "Quote" : {
    "EUR/USD" : {
      "eventSymbol" : "EUR/USD",
      "bidTime" : 1444932337000,
      "bidExchangeCode" : "",
      "bidPrice" : 1.29805,
      "bidSize" : 1,
      "askTime" : 1444932337000,
      "askExchangeCode" : "",
      "askPrice" : 1.29807,
      "askSize" : 1
    },
    "USD/AUD" : {
      "eventSymbol" : "USD/AUD",
      "bidTime" : 1444932337000,
      "bidExchangeCode" : "",
      "bidPrice" : 0.97457,
      "bidSize" : 1,
      "askTime" : 1444932337000,
      "askExchangeCode" : "",
      "askPrice" : 0.97464,
      "askSize" : 1
    }
  }
};

//Log function for demonstration
function log (s) {
  var e = document.createElement('pre');
  e.innerHTML = s;
  document.body.appendChild(e);
  console.log(s);
}

Object.keys(data["Quote"]).forEach(function (k) {
  log(k + " bid price is: " + data["Quote"][k]["bidPrice"]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(data.Quote['EUR/USD'].bidPrice);
```

The key here will be **status** and **Quote**.

```
for(var key in data){
    console.log(key);
}
```

what you really want is (as far as I understand). Key are **EUR/USD** and **USD/AUD**

```
for(var key in data.Quote){
   console.log(data.Quote[key].bidPrice);
}
```